# Spring WebFlux controller cancels Publisher subscription on first emission

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor

I have two data sources, accessed via Reactive `WebClient`s:

```
class CacheDataClient {
    Mono<Entity> createEntity(Entity entity)
}

class MasterDataClient {
    Mono<Entity> createEntity(Entity entity)
}
```

This is triggered by a call to a Spring Reactive RestController:

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public Flux<Entity> createEntity(@RequestBody Entity entity) {
    return entityService.createNewEntity(entity);
}
```

When called, my service's `createNewEntity()` method should call both sources and attempt to create a new Entity in each.

The consuming service should only care that at least one save was successful, thus **I want to immediately return the first emitted non-error value**. However, it is still necessary to wait for both publishers to complete, because I want to log an error in the event that one `WebClient` call fails.

Here is an attempt to get this working with `Flux.merge()`:

```
return Flux.merge(
        cacheClient.createEntity(entity)
                .onErrorResume(err -> {
                    log.error("Failed to create cache entity: {}", entity.getEntityGuid());
                    return Mono.empty();
                }),
        masterClient.createEntity(entity)
                .onErrorResume(err -> {
                    // IF CACHE RETURNS FIRST, THIS IS NEVER LOGGED
                    log.error("Failed to create master entity: {}", entity.getEntityGuid());
                    return Mono.empty();
                }))
    .switchIfEmpty(Flux.error(new ExternalException("Entity creation failed in cache and master")));
```

The problem is that when this code is called from my controller method, it seems that Spring returns the first value *and then cancels all future emissions*. If, however, I explicitly subscribe to the Flux.merge method above, the code behaves as expected, and any late errors are logged even after a value is published.

How can I return the first value from this Reactive Publisher from a Spring Reactive RestController without cancelling the pending emissions of the slower stream?